# Sensitivity Analysis: Global Sensitivity and Screening

Tags: probability-or-statistics, reference-request, modeling

I have a model which accepts several input parameters and now I want to study the sensitivity to certain parameters as described in here:
[Cross Validated Answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32442) and in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis).

There is also a link to [Matlab routines](http://sensitivity-analysis.jrc.ec.europa.eu/software/index.htm).

Now I'm looking for something like this for Mathematica but only found something for the [SystemModeler](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/features/analysis-mathematica.html).

Is there a package or build-in function for

- Global Sensitivity Analysis
- Local Sensitivity Analysis
- [Screening (Morris)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_method)

Comment: Since it is possible now in Mathematica 9 to use R it should be possible use an R package. I will report back when I had success with it.

Comment: I also need to do this. If I write something to do it I will share it with you here. If you have found the solution in another place Belisarius please post it here.

Comment: I haven't found any solution to this yet. The approach with R is to complicated for me (on a mac I guess). I just programmed some stuff crudely myself. If I would do it now i would maybe use MatLink and use a Matlab library.